# Javascript array within JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm trying to achieve this structure (a JSON Object with an array inside):

```
var data = {
     page : 'hello',
     rows: [
          {
              column: 'two'
          }
     ] 
}
```

But i'm failing miserable, trying various methods, this is my work in progress code:

```
var data = new Array();
    data['settings'] = [];
    var i = 0;
    var inputName, value;
    for (i; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputName = $(inputs[i]).attr('name');
        value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        data['settings'][inputName] = value;
    }
    data['page_id'] = page_id;
```

So i know the variable names are not the same as the desired example but you get the general gist! At the moment, its just making data an empty array. But i need to make it a JSON object with the idea to send it to a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've quoted is a **JavaScript** object with a JavaScript array in it, no JSON* in sight.

To create it, I don't think you want an array at all, just an object with a nested object:

```
var data = {
    settings: {},
    page_id:  page_id
};
var i, input;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    input = $(inputs[i]);
    data.settings[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
}
```

That works because JavaScript objects are *maps* of name/value pairs. You can refer to a property of an object using dotted notation and a literal property name:

```
x = obj.foo;
```

...or using bracketed notation and a *string* name:

```
x = obj["foo"];
```

In the latter case, you can use any expression you like for the string, so for instance:

```
x = obj["f" + "o" + "o"];
```

JavaScript also has literal object initializers, which you can use to create an object with properties already on it:

```
obj = {foo: "bar"};
```

That creates an object with a property called `foo` with the value `"bar"` and assigns the object to the `obj` variable.

So looking again at the code block above:

1. We create an object with the properties `settings` and `page_id`. `settings` is initialized with a blank object; `page_id` is initialized with the value of the `page_id` variable.
2. Then we loop through your `inputs` and add properties to `settings` using the name of each input, setting the value of the property to be the value of the input.

So let's assume we have

```
<input name="oneField" value="bar">
<input name="anotherField" value="bang">
<input name="yetAnotherField" value="cool">
```

...and let's assume `page_id` is `3`.

We'll end up with this structure in the object referenced by the `data` variable:

```
{
    settings: {
        oneField: "bar",
        anotherField: "bang",
        yetAnotherField: "cool"
    },
    page_id:  page_id
}
```

---

* [JSON](http://json.org) is a *textual notation*. When you're writing things like `var data = { ... };` in code, you're just using JavaScript. JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal syntax that's designed to be easy to parse, so for instance it's handy for storing arbitrary complex data in data stores, or for retrieving data from a server. You retrieve the string, which contains the data, and then *parse* that string to build up an object structure in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {};
data['settings'] = {};
var i = 0;
var inputName, value;
for (i; i < inputs.length; i++){
    inputName = $(inputs[i]).attr('name');
    value = $(inputs[i]).val();
    data['settings'][inputName] = value;
}
data['page_id'] = page_id;
```

This will give you such result like below:

```
{
     page_id: 12345,
     setting: { foo: 'one', bar: 'two'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `[]` and `new Array()` are used to initialize an array; what you're after (as you're trying to map keys to values), are objects; which are initialized using either `{}` or `new Object()`.

```
var data = {};
    data['settings'] = {};
    var i = 0;
    var inputName, value;
    for (i; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputName = $(inputs[i]).attr('name');
        value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        data['settings'][inputName] = value;
    }
    data['page_id'] = page_id;
```

To help you with your syntax, square bracket notation is only needed if the member you're looking up is a variable, or if the key contains reserved words or special characters (spaces etc). Otherwise, you can use dot notation;

```
var data = {};
    data.settings = {};
    var i = 0;
    var inputName, value;
    for (i; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputName = $(inputs[i]).attr('name');
        value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        data.settings[inputName] = value;
    }
    data.page_id = page_id;
```

When using object literal syntax (`{}`) to construct an object, you are allowed to define members on the object as well. It's also more common to declare your looping variable within the for loop rather than outside.

```
var data = {
        settings: {}
    };
    var inputName, value;
    for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputName = $(inputs[i]).attr('name');
        value = $(inputs[i]).val();
        data.settings[inputName] = value;
    }
    data.page_id = page_id;
```